# Why can't another user access my file when it's a full path?

Tags: files, permissions, directory

I have a program that runs a command that is something like this:

```
/home/myuser/bin>> /usr/bin/sudo -u otheruser script.py /home/otheruser/file.txt
```

This works, but now I need this to work when the program runs from different locations, so I changed it to use the full path:

```
/home/myuser/bin>> /usr/bin/sudo -u otheruser  /home/myuser/bin/script.py /home/otheruser/file.txt
```

That results in:

```
can't open file '/home/myuser/bin/runmacroscript.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

It's the same file, so why does a full path make a difference?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same file? Haven't you prefixed one with the `python` program? Is the path really correct?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: 1. Yes. 2. Not sure what you're talking about. 3. Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `otheruser` cannot access `/home/myuser/bin/runmacroscript.py`. The directory permissions on either or both of `/home/myuser` or `/home/myuser/bin` are too restrictive.

The reason it works when you are already in the `/home/myuser/bin` directory is that `otheruser` doesn't have to traverse the directory tree to get there.

Comment: But you don't want to relax the permissions on your home directory. You want to place the program(s) somewhere reachable and usable by others. /usr/local/bin would be one candidate.

Comment: @Chuck it's a good suggestion but I don't think we can decide whether or not relaxing permissions on a home directory is an acceptable option. Me, I'd put an application and its support libraries in `/usr/local/app/NAME` possibly with a symlink into `/usr/local/bin` but that doesn't necessarily work for anyone else

Comment: That was my caution -- opening up permissions on your home directory is not a good idea (in general).